# Estilos qss en QTDesigner

Tags: qt-designer

Estoy creando un formulario de QTDesigner, al que quiero vincular una hoja de estilos `qss`. En el formulario tengo una etiqueta definida así:

```
self.bad_creds_label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Acceso", u"Las credenciales tecleadas no son correctas", None))
```

Esto no es un problema, es el código tal como lo genera el propio QT. En el archivo de estilos tengo lo siguiente:

```
#bad_creds_label {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: red;
}
```

La idea es que esta etiqueta QLabel tenga color rojo y, por defecto, no sea visible. El archivo de estilos está correctamente vinculado al código del formulario, así:

```
app.setStyleSheet(open("qss/main.qss", "r").read())
```

El problema es que la propiedad `color` la coge bien, eso se ve porque la etiqueta aparece en rojo. Sin embargo, la propiedad `visibility` no la coge. La etiqueta debería ser no visible por defecto, pero no funciona esa propiedad. Por supuesto, la etiqueta se puede poner como invisible por programación, pero no es lo adecuado. La propiedad `visibility` es estándar de css, y debería reconocerse. Por qué no se reconoce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [sintaxis de QSS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html) es muy parecida y está inspirada en CSS, pero QSS no es CSS.

Las propiedades que están soportadas [están documentadas](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties) y `visibility` no es una de ellas, por lo que, al menos hasta la versión 6.5, no es posible establecer la visibilidad de un *widget* usando QSS.

Debes hacerlo por código, por ejemplo:

```
m_uiForm.bad_creds_label->setVisible(false);
```

Para responder directamente a tu pregunta:

> La propiedad visibility es estándar de css

El hecho de ser estándar de CSS no es relevante, es probable que haya otras propiedades estándar de CSS que tampoco estén soportadas en QSS. Refiérete siempre a la documentación oficial para determinar si algo debiera o no funcionar.

> y debería reconocerse.

No debería. Sería deseable, si, pero no hay un compromiso establecido para soportar TODO lo que se soporta en CSS.

> Por qué no se reconoce?

Esta es una pregunta que solamente los diseñadores de QSS podrían responder. No parece algo muy complejo técnicamente pero, viendo todo el trabajo que hicieron para soportar muchas de las propiedades, es de pensar que alguna razón tendrían para no incluirla. Especular cuál o cuáles son esas razones no me parece adecuado.